# How to determine capacity for threadpool for microservice in pivotal cloudfoundry?

Tags: java, spring, cloud-foundry

There is a microservice (spring-boot based) deployed to pivotal cloudfoundry. It creates asynchronous task to process long requests. The implementation is newFixedThreadPool.

How to determine capacity for the threadpool?

Regularly, I will look for CPU load to be 80-90%. But pivotal cloudfoundry CPU load can be more than 100%. As I understand it is time of consuming CPU divided by time from previous checkpoint. And I don't know what is the maximum value 200, 400, 800 or more. I assume it is related to number of cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only answer that can stand here on its own, and also work for future readers: you will have to ask the provider of your cloud service.

Meaning: the *ideal* configuration for your thread pool (and probably many other configuration possibilities) is a very special thing. It depends on the actual policies that your service provider has in place. And those policies change over time. What works today might be less than optimal in 6 months.

In that sense: don't expect that people on the internet can tell you what works best for service X for requirements Y on day Z. Therefore my suggestion would be to not ask for "generic" advice here - but to carefully check what the help pages (or support people) of your current service provider have to say.

Of course, you can *try* to simply use JVM calls such as `Runtime.getAvailableProcessors()`. But that is actually tricky business, see issues [135](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue135.html) and [220](https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue220.html) of the Java specialist newsletter for example.

Comment: Also, don't base your scaling on CPU.  The further you get away from bare metal, the harder it is to make meaningful plans based on CPU usage.  Instead look for metrics or KPIs that are based on other factors.  For your example, you could look at things like the number of active/idle threads under load, request wait or queue time, relevant 4xx/5xx counts, etc.